# DevExpress Pivot Grid: custom calculation of cells

Tags: c#, devexpress, pivot-table, devexpress-wpf

I have a WPF Pivot Grid control from DevExpress.

My Pivot Grid accepts as an input a table with three fields: Amount (`FieldArea.DataArea`), Country (`FieldArea.RowArea`), Product (`FieldArea.ColumnArea`).

A basic customization of Pivot Grid would show me in each cell the sum of Amount for a given Country and a given Product.

I want to fill the cells with the following:

a) if `Country <> "XLand"`, the cell should show the `sum(Amount)` for given Country and Product divided by the sum(Amount) for all the records except those with `Country=="XLand"`

b) if `Country=="XLand"`, the cell should show 5.

Have no idea how to do it. Would be very happy to see any example or any reference explaining a functionality for this.

Thanks for any comment!